# Go printing wierd output

Tags: go

When I execute below code in Online Go compiler it works as expected, but when I execute this code in my computer(Golang 1.17.5). It prints weird output.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)
//variables
var (
    countries = []string{"au", "in", "jp", "kr", "tr"}
    country   string
)
//main function
func main() {
    if len(os.Args) < 2 {
        fmt.Printf("country code : ")
        fmt.Scanf("%s", &country)
        checkcountry(&country)

        // log.Printf("")
    } else {
        checkcountry(&country)

    }

}
```

//check whether the entered string is in countries string_array

```
func checkcountry(country *string) {

    for 1 == 1 {

        if is_string_in_array(*country, countries) {
            fmt.Printf("country : %s, breaking\n", *country)
            break
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("country code : ")
            fmt.Scanf("%s", country)
        }
    }

}
```

```
func is_string_in_array(str string, array []string) bool {
    for _, i := range array {
        if str == i {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

repl.it terminal output :

```
go run main.go
country code : dd
country code :
```

my terminal output :

```
go run main.go
country code : dd
country code : country code :
```

Comment: I think you have put space after "dd" in your terminal input. "dd " instead of "dd"

Comment: Or you're on windows and not accounting for the `\r`

Comment: I'm very new to Programming, can you please tell me what's needs to done here or redirect to relevant  article

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `fmt.Scanf` you can use `bufio` package to read input as shown in below example which parse input till newline.

```golang
reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
fmt.Print("Enter text: ")
text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
fmt.Println(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `fmt.Scanf` you should probably use [bufio.Scanner](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio@go1.17.6#Scanner) which is a little smarter in detecting newlines and whitespace.

```
func main() {
  scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
  fmt.Println("Country code:")
  scanner.Scan()
  text := scanner.Text()
  fmt.Println(text)
}
```